# Best way to have two XSLT templates apply to same element

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<data>
    <admin id="abc">
        <type>one</type>
        <!-- <detail/> might appear here but the content is unrelated to <detail/> below -->
    </admin>
    <detail id="def">
        <name>Bob</name>
    </detail>
</data>
```

I then have XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/data/admin">
    Admin content
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/detail">
    Some content to appear before ALL types.  This id is <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/data/admin/type='one'>
            Content for type One only.  Your name is <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/data/admin/type='two'>
            Content for type Two only.  Your name is still <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Content if the type is not set or set to an unknown value
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    Some content to appear after ALL types.  This id is <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Because the `<xsl:choose/>` is quite large, I want to split it into different files - one per condition - and `<xsl:include/>` them into the main document.

The problem I have is that `<xsl:include/>` requires each included file to contain templates, I can't include raw data.  So I am left with these choices:

- In each included file, use `<xsl:template match="/data/detail"/>` - this then overrides the parent template above, so I have to copy and paste the data "for ALL types" into each file.  This is not good because of the data duplication.
- In each included file, use something like `<xsl:template match="/data/admin/type='one'"/>` and then put in a call to `<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/admin/type"/>`.  This won't work because then in the "Admin content" template I will have an inadvertent template instance for the child `<type/>` node that I don't want.
- Define each block of content as a named template, then inside my `<xsl:choose/>` call each one by name.  This seems kind of untidy when XSLT should be able to select the right template without me naming it explicitly.

Is there a neater way this can be achieved?

The output should look like this:

```
Admin content
Some content to appear before ALL types.  This id is def
Content for type One only.  Your name is Bob
Some content to appear after ALL types.  This id is def
```

Comment: Please provide full sample input XML. From your sample isn't clear is `detail` part of `admin` or it is just general element.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: It's a general element that can appear anywhere, I've updated the question to mention this specifically.

Comment: Your input XML contains just single `admin` element or multiple?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: Same as for `detail`.  Each element (`admin` and `detail`) will appear exactly once under the top level `<data/>` node, but unrelated elements with the same names may appear under `/data/admin` and `/data/detail`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the content before/after/inside elements is? Are the `data/details` being wrapped, or just having elements come before? Is the content before static or based on other elements?

Comment: The `data/details` are being wrapped, with content coming before and after the conditional content.  The before/after content includes values that are taken from attributes on the `<detail/>` tag.  I will update the question to be clearer on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have two different templates matching two different XPaths, one for each type, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='one']/detail">
    <!-- Type one specific transform -->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='two']/detail">
    <!-- Type two specific transform -->
</xsl:template>
```

Each of these templates can be in their own file, and each file is included.

Comment: Where would you place content that should appear before and after your matching templates?  (i.e. the text `Some content to appear for ALL types` in my example XSLT), without duplicating it inside each template?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to the answer given by @Lego Stormtroopr. He suggests starting with two templates each matching one type:

```
<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='one']/detail">
 <!-- Type one specific transform -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='two']/detail">
 <!-- Type two specific transform -->
</xsl:template>
```

Now for the `content to appear for ALL types`, here are two possibilities. If the part appearing for all types is about *content*, use a global variable and store it there:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1">
 <!--Content for all types-->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='one']/detail">
 <!-- content for ALL types example: -->
 <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
 <!-- Go on with type specific content -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='two']/detail">
 <!-- content for ALL types example: -->
 <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
 <!-- Go on with type specific content -->
</xsl:template>
```

If there are input elements inside `detail` that you need to catch, just define another template for them and let `apply-templates` find them.

```
<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='one']/detail">
 <!-- content for ALL types example: -->
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 <!-- Go on with type specific content -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data[admin/type='two']/detail">
 <!-- content for ALL types example: -->
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 <!-- Go on with type specific content -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[parent::detail]">
 <!--template content-->
</xsl:template>
```